# Obtaining radio button values for use in switch statement in PHP

Tags: php

I've having a difficult time trying to figure out how to obtain the value of a radio button for use in a switch statement. Basically, when the user selects one of the radio buttons, I want the action for that radio button to be performed. Not sure if I'm setting this up right or not. I'm learning PHP on my own and have no idea if this is the correct way to do this. Below is the HTML and PHP.

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="calculate" value="average" checked="checked">Average<br />
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="calculate" value="total">Total<br />
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="calculate" value="both">Both<br />
```

Here is the PHP

```
$calculate_type = $_POST['calculate'];
    switch ($calculate_type) {
        case '$calculate_type == "average"':
            $score_average = $score_total / count($scores);
            break;
        case '$calculate_type == "total"':
            $score_total = $scores[0] + $scores[1] + $scores[2];
            break;
        case '$calculate_type == "both"':
            $score_average = $score_total / count($scores);
            $score_total = $scores[0] + $scores[1] + $scores[2];
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Try: `case $calculate_type == "average":` remove the quotes

Answer (score 2):

Where on earth did you learn to write a `switch` statment like that???

```
switch($calculate_type) {
  case "average":
    // do something
    break;
  case "total":
    // do something else
    break;
  case "both":
    // do something completely different
    break;
  default: die("Invalid type");
}
```

Then again, in this case it'd be better as the following:

HTML:

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="calculate" value="1" checked="checked">Average<br />
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="calculate" value="2">Total<br />
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="calculate" value="3">Both<br />
```

PHP:

```
if( $_POST['calculate'] & 1) $score_average = $score_total / count($scores);
if( $_POST['calculate'] & 2) $score_total = $scores[0]+$scores[1]+$scores[2];
```